# USB 3.0 Card Reader 40 in 1 (Delock)

Tags: 14.04, usb, sd-card, card-reader

I bought a Delock USB 3.0 card reader (http://www.delock.com/produkte/G_91718/merkmale.html) to read my Canon's 64GB SDCX card on my Lenovo Carbon X1 (gen2) notebook. The reader with the said card works fine both on Windows 7.1 and Mac (Yosemite). The SD card is formatted by the Canon EOS 40D camera.

When I connect the reader with the card inserted, most of the times nothing happens.  When I first plug the reader and THEN the card in it, it is recognised and mounted automatically but when I access the /DCIM/100CANON folder (where the images are stored), the volume disappears from the system.

My notebook offers 2 USB 3.0 ports that can be configured via the BIOS settings as:

1. Auto (auto selection between 2.0 & 3.0 controller)
2. Enabled (force USB 3.0)
3. Disabled (operate as 2.0)

The first 2 options result in the above behaviour. The 3rd allows for normal operation of the card reader but of course speed is reduced down to USB 2.0 (not to mention that I have to reboot and change BIOS settings every time I need to connect the SD card).

Any help so I can make this reader work under usb 3 specifications would be appreciated!

**UPDATE 1:**
Upon a friend's recommendation, I tested the Card reader on other Ubuntu systems using an Ubuntu Live Usb (v.14.04.02). I checked on a desktop PC and then on the very same Lenovo notebook. In both cases, the reader worked perfectly at USB 3.0 speeds, after I installed the required packages `exfat-utils exfat-fuse`. So, the problem seems to lie somewhere within my Ubuntu installation and not on the Lenovo hardware. [Here you can find](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzfRnL1J2m8ObC0zdnpHV3lnYWc/view?usp=sharing) the Crash Report of Ubuntu that I received one time after the volume disappeared.

**System Info:** 
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS; 3.13.0-58-generic

**Commands output:**

$ dmesg | grep -i usb

```
[   73.575740] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   78.589959] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   83.708104] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   84.108191] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   84.125912] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0743
[   84.125921] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[   84.125926] usb 3-1: Product: USB Storage
[   84.125930] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[   84.125934] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[   84.178125] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   84.178267] scsi3 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[   84.180895] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  184.412123] usb 2-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  185.439799] usb 2-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  186.555296] usb 2-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  191.045810] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  195.867674] usb 3-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[  196.387466] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -22
[  627.528367] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  627.528448] usb 2-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  627.732283] usb 2-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  627.936151] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[  628.104619] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  628.123066] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0743
[  628.123076] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  628.123081] usb 3-1: Product: USB Storage
[  628.123085] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[  628.123088] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 000000000819
[  628.128151] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  628.128454] scsi4 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
```

*After it disconnects:*

```
[ 2929.227500] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 2934.053729] usb 3-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 2934.573512] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -22
```

$ sudo lshw

```
*-scsi:1
      physical id: 3
      bus info: usb@3:1
      logical name: scsi4
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: STORAGE DEVICE
         vendor: Generic
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 0819
         serial: 000000000819
         size: 59GiB (63GB)
         capabilities: removable
         configuration: ansiversion=6 sectorsize=512
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/sdb
            size: 59GiB (63GB)
            capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          *-volume
               description: HPFS/NTFS partition
               physical id: 1
               logical name: /dev/sdb1
               logical name: /media/zark/EOS_DIGITAL
               capacity: 59GiB
               capabilities: primary
               configuration: mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
```

*(shows nothing relevant after disconnect)*

$ lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 450.8G  0 part /media/Iomega500
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  18.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1  59.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  59.5G  0 part /media/zark/EOS_DIGITAL
```

*(shows nothing relevant after disconnect)*

$ lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7036 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0743 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: The problem still persists with no solution yet...